# How to add numbers to a string with Python or GREL

Tags: python, openrefine, grel

I have ***>4000*** numbers in a column that need to be manipulated..
They look like this:
**040 413 560 89 or 0361 223240**

How dow I put it into the folllowing format:
**+49 (040) 41356089 or +49 (0361) 223240**

They all need to have the same country dialling code **+49** and then the respective area code put into brackets and ***some are already in the correct format.***

Comment: What have you try to do? Please provide some code, we are here to help, not to do it for you

Comment: What do you mean by *'column'*? What data structure are you dealing with? Show a simplification of your code. I noticed another question you'd asked which is very similar. Be specific. See how to create a [mcve]. What is your precise problem (i.e. what you're unable to do), rather than what is your goal?

Comment: Hi Peter. By column I means as in an excel column for example. to be exact Im working on openrefine which accepts GREL or Python for editing the data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do so like this:

```
ls_alreadycorrected = ['(',')','+49']
str_in = '040 413 560 89' #or apply to list

for flag in ls_alreadycorrected:
    if flag not in str_in:
        how_many_spaces = str_in.count(' ')
        if how_many_spaces > 2:
            str_in = str_in.replace(' ','')
            str_out = '+049'+' ' + '(' + str_in[:3] + ') ' + str_in[-8:]
        else:
            str_in = str_in.replace(' ','')
            str_out = '+049'+' ' + '(' + str_in[:4] + ') ' + str_in[-6:]
```

That's only given you have to types of phone numbers. For a list of numbers, put this on top instead of str_in

```
for number in list_of_numbers:
    str_in = number
```

Cheers

Comment: thanks dmb however seems to give me an error message on openrefine

Comment: @Mac This is for Python Standard Lib

Answer (score 0):

We can split the string into groups:

```
>>> groups = '040 413 560 89'.split()
>>> groups
['040', '413', '560', '89']
```

We can slice the groups, and assign to variables, also join the later groups into one string:

```
>>> city, number = groups[0], ''.join(groups[1:])
>>> city, number
('040', '41356089')
```

We can format a new string:

```
>>> '+49 ({}) {}'.format(city, number)
'+49 (040) 41356089'
```

We can check if a number already starts with `+`:

```
>>> '+49 (040) 41356089'.startswith('+')
True
```

Comment: hmm  thanks. but I have a column with +4000 numbers to need to apply to all of them simultaneously. How can I use .startswith to add +49 to any number that doesnt already have it?

Comment: Improve the original question. See [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score -2):

You can do this.

```
phone  = "456789"
cod = 123

final = str(cod) + phone
```

Result is `"123456789"`